# how to change week date on textbox by click on next and prev button

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I Have two buttons like

```
         <input type="button" value="Prev" id="btnPrev"/> //for Previous week date
         <input type="button" value="Prev" id="btnNext"/> // for Next week date
```

and Textbox like:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.START_DATE, new { @id = "txtStartDate", @style = "height:22px;width:100px;border:none;background-color: transparent;text-align:right", @readonly = "readonly" }) -
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.END_DATE, new { @id = "txtEndDate", @style = "height:22px;width:100px;border:none;background-color: transparent;", @readonly = "readonly" })
```

start date textbox is for displaying start date of the current week and End date text box is for displaying end date of current week.

I have script like to display start date and end date of the current week is

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var curr = new Date; // get current date
        var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay(); // First day is the day of the month - the day of the week
        var last = first + 6; // last day is the first day + 6
        var startDate = new Date(curr.setDate(first));
        startDate = "0" + (startDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + startDate.getDate() + "/" + startDate.getFullYear();
        var endDate = new Date(curr.setDate(last));
        endDate = "0" + (endDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + endDate.getDate() + "/" + endDate.getFullYear();
        var A = new Date().getWeek();
        $('#txtStartDate').val(startDate);
        $('#txtEndDate').val(endDate);
        });
```

But I didn't getting idea how to change the week date by click on next week button and previous button that should display next week end and previous week end. Please help  me anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got It.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var curr = new Date; // get current date
        var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay(); // First day is the day of the month - the day of the week
        var last = first + 6; // last day is the first day + 6
        var startDate = new Date(curr.setDate(first));
        startDate = "0" + (startDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + startDate.getDate() + "/" + startDate.getFullYear();
        var endDate = new Date(curr.setDate(last));
        endDate = "0" + (endDate.getMonth() + 2) + "/" + endDate.getDate() + "/" + endDate.getFullYear();
        var A = new Date().getWeek();
        $('#txtStartDate').val(startDate);
        $('#txtEndDate').val(endDate);
        $("#btnNext").click(function () {
            var startdt=new Date($('#txtStartDate').val());
            startdt.setDate(startdt.getDate() + 7);// Adding 7 Days
            $('#txtStartDate').val(getDateFormat(startdt));

            var enddt =new Date( $('#txtEndDate').val());
            enddt.setDate(enddt.getDate() + 7); 
            $('#txtEndDate').val(getDateFormat(enddt));
            return false;
        });
        function getDateFormat(d) {
            var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
            return "0" + +month + "/" + d.getDate() + "/" + d.getFullYear();

        }

        $("#btnPrev").click(function () {
            var startdt = new Date($('#txtStartDate').val());
            startdt.setDate(startdt.getDate() - 7); // subtracting 7 before
            $('#txtStartDate').val(getDateFormat(startdt));
            var enddt = new Date($('#txtEndDate').val());
            enddt.setDate(enddt.getDate() - 7); 
            $('#txtEndDate').val(getDateFormat(enddt));
            return false;
        });
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vLEhb/)

```
$('#picker').datepicker();
$('.next-day').on("click", function () {
var date = $('#picker').datepicker('getDate');
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (1000*60*60*24))
$('#picker').datepicker("setDate", date);
});

$('.prev-day').on("click", function () {
var date = $('#picker').datepicker('getDate');
date.setTime(date.getTime() - (1000*60*60*24))
$('#picker').datepicker("setDate", date);            
});
```

Comment: Thanks..!! But I don't want to use date picker , i want to jump next week and previous week by click on buttons using javascript only.@Min2

Comment: Yes, But i got in different approach.